# Condition not working for 2 different apps in a Django template

Tags: django

I have created a project with 2 apps:
1.Core for items model to be viewed in home page
2. Score with posts model

The home.html is mainly for listing items by designers, the designers/users might have posts as well so I am trying to show buttons for designers/userswho have posts and hide them if the users don't have posts.

I have added the code but the button for the designers/usersposts is still showing.

App No. 1 CORE

Core Models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Core views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
    # context_object_name = 'posts' (I have commented this part as it is from Score Models 
when included the home page become 404 error)
```

Here is the Core URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

App No.2 Score
Score Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)
```

Home.html template

```
{% if post.designer %}

  <a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' item.designer.username %}"> 
  <button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" 
class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
   Check my posts</button>
   </a>

{% else %}

Show Nothing

{% endif %}
```

I dont know what might the reason for now working I have used the same logic with other templates but didnt succeed in this trial

Comment: can you post your full html template, do you have loop above

Comment: You can do  that with only one App, why did you chose to use 2 Apps?

Comment: @iklinac yes there is loop above but `{% for item in object_list %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this solution to your project.

model.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)


class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)


class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.design)
```

views.py:

```
def myview(request):
    msg = ''
    qs1 = Item.objects.all().values_list('designer')
    qs2 = Post.objects.all().values_list('designer')
    for result in list(set(qs1) & set(qs2)):
        msg += '<a href = "www.google.com"><button style = "margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" type = "button" ' \
               'class ="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" > Check my posts : {0}</button></a><br>'.\
            format(User.objects.get(pk=result[0]))
    context = {'msg': msg}
    return render(request, 'stack/home.html', context)
```

home.html

```
<body>
      {% autoescape off %}
      {{ msg }}
      {% endautoescape %}

</body>
```